# How to redirect the user to the url after the password confirmation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, express, redirect

The idea:

I have a protected route "/me" and EACH TIME user tries to get there, he should enter his password (even if the user has been logged in already). If password is correct, then user goes to "/me" route.

---

The problem:

I use express. There is a middleware called "confirm-transaction" on "/me" route. And when user goes to "/me" route this middleware redirects user to "/confirm-transaction?redirect=/me" and user can see a field where he should enter his password.

And in this moment I don't know what to do, because if password is correct I try to redirect user to "/me" route (I get this route from "?redirect=/me" param), but the middleware again redirects him to "/confirm-transaction?redirect=/me". And user can never get to "/me" route.

---

The question is:

How can I solve this situation? I know that I should use "next()" if password is correct, but I can't do it as middleware does a redirect and I have no more "next()"

---

Here is some code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const server = express();

const requestAuthorization = (req, res, next) => {
  res.redirect(301, `/confirm-transaction?redirect=${req.originalUrl}`);
};

server.get('/me', requestAuthorization, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("this is /me route");
});

server.get('/confirm-transaction', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile("password.html");
  // there is a form with field and button with POST method to '/confirm-transaction'
});

server.post('/confirm-transaction', (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.password === 'testpassword') { // it is a fake password (for testing)
     res.redirect(301, req.query.redirect);
  }
  res.redirect(301, `/confirm-transaction?redirect=${req.query.redirect}`);
});
```

Comment: You can use the user's session; after they've entered the password, store in their session that access is allowed. On the `/me` route, only redirect if they aren't allowed yet, and if they are, reset the session variable before serving the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is a good way to go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/me` blindly redirects to `/confirm-transaction` no matter what.

What you can do is to:
1. send user a token (or some sort) after successful authorization. Client stores it then the next request should have that token in the header.
2. Inside `requestAuthorization()` check if request header has valid token. If it does, dont redirect, otherwise, redirect.

Note: in you case, you might have to redirect with token in the header.
Note: that you have to store the token somewhere that has access to match the token with the user.